# Django exclude for same field with different values

Tags: python, django

I have to create a query like this:

```
Obj.objects.exclude(title__iexact="Hello", title_iexact="Hell")
```

I want to create the exclude query as a dictionary from a list and use kwargs to pass it to exclude. Is it possible?

I know it will never exclude any records because of the impossible condition. But, this query comes from a parser, so I need to make sure it can be given properly to the SQL engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it... Q objects... below link is pretty good...

http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2010/07/20/the-power-of-djangos-q-objects/

Some code:

```
for rule in rules:
    negative_rules.append((rule.key.lower() + "__" + "iexact", rule.value))

negative_rules = reduce(operator.or_, [Q(x) for x in negative_rules]) if negative_rules else Q()

Obj.objects.exclude(negative_rules)
```